# Given $A := \{ \frac{n^2}{2^n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, prove $\inf A = 0$ using the definition of the infimum

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given that $$A := \{ \frac{n^2}{2^n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Show that  $\inf A = 0$ using the definition of the infimum. The definition that we have been using in class is that $\inf A = \alpha$ if

$1)\;\forall x, \;x \in A,$ the inequality $x \ge \alpha$ is true

$2)\;\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists x_0 \in A: x_0 < \alpha + \epsilon$

I have attempted to get $n$ to one side of the inequality.
$$ \exists n_0 \in A: \frac{n_0^2}{2^{n_0}} < 0 + \epsilon $$

$$ \frac{n_0^2}{2^{n_0}} <  \epsilon$$

$$n^2 < \epsilon \;·\;2^n $$

$$n^2 - \epsilon \;·\;2^n < 0 $$

I am not sure where to go further with this since in all other exercises I've done, $\epsilon$ and $n_0$ end up in separate terms. My attempt to use logarithm rules has also failed:

$$\ln(\frac{n_0^2}{2^{n_0}}) < \ln(\epsilon)$$
$$\ln(n_0^2) - \ln(2^{n_0}) < \ln(\epsilon)$$
$$\ln(n_0^2) - n_0 \ln(2) < \ln(\epsilon)$$
$$\ln(n_0^2) < \ln(\epsilon) + n_0 \ln(2)$$
$$\frac{\ln(n_0^2)}{\ln(2)} < \frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(2)} + n_0$$
$$n_0 > 2\ln(\frac{n_0}{2}) - \ln(\frac{\epsilon}{2})$$
Where do I do I go forward with this?

Some context: this is the first semester that I have any higher mathematics classes for my computer science degree, so please be considerate of my surface-level understanding of the subject.

Comment: Hint: Set $ n_0 = 2^k$, can you find an expression involving $k$ and $\epsilon$?

Comment: Since I presume you are not familiar with limits (in which case you could use L'Hôpital's rule), how about using proof by contradiction? Assume $\inf A$ is not $0$, and then use definition of infimum to derive contradiction. In fact, in the case of $\inf A > 0$ you can use point 1) to derive contradiction, and in the case of $\inf A < 0$ you can use point 2) nicely.

Comment: @StanislavVeklenko How would you derive a contradiction when $\inf A > 0$? Note that point 1) does not imply $\inf A \le 0$. In fact, it implies $\inf A\ge 0$. So you would still need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2/2^n=0$ somehow.

Comment: @durianice show that for every $\alpha = \inf A > 0$, we can find some $x(\alpha) \in A \mid x < \alpha$.

Comment: @StanislavVeklenko Yeah, and that would be the same as showing for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is $n_0>0$ such that $n_0^2/2^{n_0}<\varepsilon$, which is what OP wants to show.

Comment: assume $\alpha = \inf A > 0$. Then $\exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N} \mid \alpha > \frac{1}{n_{0}}$. But this implies $\exists x \in A \mid x=\frac{n_{0}^2}{2^{n_{0}}}<\frac{n_{0}^2}{n_{0}^3}=\frac{1}{n_{0}}<\alpha$. This works $\forall n_{0}\geq 10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to find a large enough $n$ so that $\frac{n^2}{2^n}$ is arbitrarily small.
Considering you are a CS major,
you probably know that $O(2^n)$ is much larger than $O(n^2)$ from complexity analysis.
Here is one way to show this.
Look what happens when we double the $n$ in $\frac{n^2}{2^n}$:
$$
\frac{(2n)^2}{2^{2n}}=\frac{4n^2}{2^{2n}}=\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\frac{n}{2^n}.
$$
So, when we double the size of $n$, the size of $\frac{n}{2^n}$ is scaled down by a factor of $\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$.
Now, the question becomes:

> Given $\varepsilon$ and given (say) $n=1$, how many times do we need to double the $n$ so that $\frac{n}{2^n}$ becomes smaller than $\varepsilon$?

In fact, we do not need to figure out exactly how many times it takes.
We can choose a ridiculously large number and call it a day.
Let $\varepsilon>0$.
By Archimedean principle, there exists integer $N>0$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon$.
There certainly exists integer $M>0$ such that $2^{M-2}>N$,
so that $\frac{1}{2^{M-2}}<\frac{1}{N}$.
Now we can simply choose $n_0=2M$.
Then
$$
\frac{n_0^2}{2^{n_0}}=\frac{(2M)^2}{2^{2M}}=\frac{1}{2^{M-2}}\frac{M}{2^M}<\frac{1}{2^{M-2}}<\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon,
$$
where we have used $\frac{M}{2^M}<1$, which is not hard to prove.